# Android overlay window using jetpack compose

Tags: android, popup, android-jetpack-compose

I need to develop an android library that should be able to allow the developer, who is using my library, to show an overlay window on top of his current screen. I can use popup overlay for this, but the overlay UI should be declarative. I am trying to use Jetpack compose to create a declarative UI for overlay.
I have created a simple popup in a kotlin file like below

```
class MyView {
@Composable
    fun pop() {
        Box {
            val popupWidth = 200.dp
            val popupHeight = 50.dp
            val cornerSize = 16.dp

            Popup(alignment = Alignment.Center) {
                // Draw a rectangle shape with rounded corners inside the popup
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .size(popupWidth, popupHeight)
                        .background(Color.White, RoundedCornerShape(cornerSize))
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To test this, I have created an activity with a button like below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
 @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    fun showComposeView(view: android.view.View)
    {
        setContent {
            MyView().pop()
        }
    }
}
```

layout file for above activity is as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="showComposeView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now, the problem is, when I click on the button, the view from the above layout file is getting replaced by compose popup.

I want to compose popup to be displayed on the existing layout view.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am able show compose pop up on existing layout using Bottom sheet dialog fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `setContent{}` is effectively like calling `setContentView`, you replace the root `View` of your `Activity`.

What you're trying to do is mixing both `Compose` and regular `View`, your best option is probably to put your layout in an `AndroidView` Composable.
You can find more info [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis)

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyPopupContainer(@LayoutRes layout: Int) {
    var showPopup by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    AndroidView(factory = { context ->

        // Inflate your view the way you want, using layout inflater or ViewBinding
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, null)

        view.findViewById<View>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
            showPopup = true
        }
        
        // returning the view we just created
        view
    })

    // When showPopup is false, your popup won't be displayed
    if (showPopup) {
        // Your popup function here
        MyView().pop()
    }
}
```

Then in your `Activity`

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent { MyPopupContainer(R.layout.your_xml_layout) }
    }
```